# Flex 4 Scroller

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, scroll

Within my application I'm using a [Scroller](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html) component. I can't seem to figure out which event I should set up a listener on in order to know when content is scrolled. I tried `Event.CHANGE` on `Scroller.verticalScrollBar` property but apparently that event doesn't fire when the user scrolls with a mouse wheel or arrow keys.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can listen for the propertyChange event on the viewport of the Scroller.  Here is an application that demonstrates how this might be done:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.PropertyChangeEvent;

            private function init():void {
                // spark Scroller: listen on the viewport property
                myScroller.viewport.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, handle);
            }

            /**
             * Handle scroll position changes
             */
            private function handle(e:PropertyChangeEvent):void {
                if (e.source == e.target && e.property == "verticalScrollPosition")
                    trace(e.property, "changed to", e.newValue);
                if (e.source == e.target && e.property == "horizontalScrollPosition")
                    trace(e.property, "changed to", e.newValue);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Scroller id="myScroller" width="100" height="100">
        <s:Group>
            <s:Button label="large content" width="300" height="300"/>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. If only you'd posted earlier. Either way, I ended up doing something similar by setting up a ChangeWatcher on those two properties of the IViewport.

Answer (score 0):

```
slidePanel.slidesComponentsContainer.slidesList.scroller.addEventListener(
  TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_START,
  onSlideListVertScrollerTouchInteractionStart
);
```