# Event when the scroller starts scrolling or ending scrolling in Flex 4.0

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, scroller

are there any events that the scroller will dispatch when being scrolled?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the `Scroller` component doesn't dispatch an event when it's scrolling the way the [ScrollBar class did in Flex 3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/ScrollEvent.html). You can read up more on `Scrollers` and `Viewports` on [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Spark+Viewport) and [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_viewport_scrolling.html).

Comment: thanks.. i had to use the change watcher on the viewports verticalscroll postion

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear you figured it out. If my answer helped you solve your problem, an upvote and marking it as the answer would be most appreciated. :)

Comment: This thread might be useful for detecting scroll position changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390725/flex-4-scroller/4425091#4425091

Comment: @Steven Shongrunden, Great find! Definitely bookmarking that one for later.